# WPF ItemTemplate Causing ListBox Content Size Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, size, datatemplate, itemtemplate

In a WPF project, I have a `ListBox` that renders correctly if I manually insert items in XAML, e.g.:

```
<ListBoxItem>
    <Grid Background="#7F271043" Width="200" Height="200">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="110" />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="Logo-40p.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,10,10,10" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Test Item" Foreground="White" Margin="10,0,10,0" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <local:Rating Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="130" SelectedValue="4" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Free" Foreground="#FF969292" Margin="0,0,10,0" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</ListBoxItem>
```

The bottom of the `ListBoxItem` looks like:

[image: Manual Item Insertion]

However, the moment I swap out `<ListBoxItem>` for:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
```

Even if I keep everything else identical, it creates a sizing problem with my rating control that I'm unable to fix (doesn't respond to manual size or stretch settings):

[image: ItemTemplate]

Any thoughts on how to address this? Do `ItemTemplate` / `DataTemplate` do something that might cause a control to not respect the size manually set or set by the grid row it's in?

Comment: Please show us your datatemplate. Before you do though, check whether it's missing that height and width on it's grid. For a good answer it's by far best if you provide the minimum code, markup etc that reproduces your issue. Otherwise, it's rather like going into a garage without your car and asking them why it doesn't start.

Comment: In the example above, I literally just swapped out <ListBoxItem> ... </ListBoxItem> for <ListBox.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate> ... </DataTemplate></ListBox.ItemTemplate> - so the content inside is identical to the XAML above (not even binding anything - the size issue pops up immediately just by switching over from ListBoxItem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this - it seems that a manually defined `ListBoxItem` in XAML behaves differently from the output of an `ItemTemplate` / `DataTemplate`.

My rating user control had a set height and width specified that were overridden by the implementation XAML (height/width/stretch) inside a `ListBoxItem` but not inside a `ItemTemplate` / `DataTemplate`:

```
mc:Ignorable="d" Height="750" Width="4070" MouseLeave="UserControl_MouseLeave">
```

So I instead changed `Height` / `Width` to `DesignHeight` / `DesignWidth` to fix the issue:

```
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="750" d:DesignWidth="4070" MouseLeave="UserControl_MouseLeave">
```